# Intermittently getting exception org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It happens on all browsers.
I have Windows 10.
Chrome Version 80.0.3987.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Selenium Java client 3.141.59

Here is the exception:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:46062
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-C6KTGKN5', ip: '10.0.0.207', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.2'

Here is the snippet of the code:

```
    driver.get("https://www.trademe.co.nz/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String titleToSwitch = "Car auctions";
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Policies")).click();        
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cars")).click();

    Set<String> allWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String window : allWindows)
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if ((driver.getTitle()).contains(titleToSwitch))
            break;
    }

    driver.findElement(By.name("searchString")).sendKeys("Acura TL");
    driver.findElement(By.className("btn")).click();
    WebElement searchResults = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".attSearchResultList.advanced-motors-att"));
```

It happens after the last statement.
Please, help.

Comment: This program worked fine for me. It doesn't seem to be a problem in code.

Comment: As I wrote, it works from time to time. Run it for 6 times. It always happens after the last statement. Search reloads the page. I assume it somehow related.

Comment: I hope you are using this chromedriver version. If not try with this https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using the latest version of the ChromeDriver. I also saw that exception with other browsers from time to time.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with code. I too had encountered this error but rarely. You can try to match the chrome driver version against the browser version. viz. Chrome driver v.80 with chrome browser v.80. Try with Java 8.

Comment: The drivers match, but I use Java 13.